# i keep getting a Value error in python

Tags: python

I am new to programming  I decided I would make a basic maths game. I started 
    print ("what is your name")
    name = input ()
    print ("hello " + name + " i am steve and this is my maths test. Are you ready? Y/N")
    answer_1 = input ()
    answer_1 = int (answer_1)

```
if answer_1 ==Y:
    print ("Good then lets get started")

else:
    print ("well you have started now so to late lets go")
```

I went to test it and every time I do I get this.

```
what is your name
Callum
hello Callum i am steve and this is my maths test. Are you ready? Y/N
Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\callum\Documents\programming\maths test.py", line 6, in <module>
answer_1 = int (answer_1)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Y'
>>>
```

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong

Comment: how do you want python to convert Y to int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
if answer_1 == 'Y':
```

And don't convert it to an integer...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert the letter 'y' into a base 10 number.

Take this line out of your code.

```
answer_1 = int (answer_1)
```

Also when you are testing for string equality, remember to use quotation marks or the python interpreter won't know if you mean a variable name or the actual string 'Y'.

```
if answer_1 =='Y':
    print ("Good then lets get started")
```

Answer (score 0):

you are converting the string input from this line

```
answer_1 = input ()
```

into an integer here

```
answer_1 = int (answer_1)
```

this will not work if the input is "Y".

Then you compare this input with Y, but you should compare with the string "Y" here:

```
if answer_1 ==Y:
```

finally, i think it is not a good idea to have spaces in programming-related filesnames.

Comment: What do you mean by "i think it is not a good idea to have spaces in programming-related files."?

Comment: @MartinThompson filenames. edited. `File "C:\Users\callum\Documents\programming\maths test.py"`

Comment: Ahh, I see - in programming related file *names*!  Personally, I think it's fine... in fact the sooner you get used to expecting spaces in pathnames, the better.  "Normal users" use them all the time and then your code will break on them.  I'm forever frustrated by the variety of professional-grade CAE software which fails to deal with spaces in pathnames/filenames!

Comment: definitely a best practice to support unusual filenames, but if you require a beginner to follow all best practices before letting her do something meaningful, they will drop out before ever achieving anything. and especially around the shell properly supporting strange filenames is very hard and not worth the pain, so imho it is best to avoid the problem for some time. and in this case i could argue that it should be a valid module name --- and swoosh -- we already are in territory where we scare away the beginners. some examples: utf8. localization. right2left. cross-platform. python3. lint.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line : `answer_1 = int (answer_1)`
and change this `if answer_1 == Y:` to `if answer_1 == 'Y':`